# Flutter and react native - Play Store

Tags: flutter, react-native

is it possible to build apk and ipa files on flutter without uploading them to playmarket and app store, also see how you can build apk and ipa files on react native expo without uploading them to playmarket and app store

I don't exactly know how to do that

Comment: Have you looked in the docs? The React Native docs tell you how to do this

Comment: Please edit the question to limit it to a specific problem with enough detail to identify an adequate answer.

Answer (score 0):

Run `flutter build apk` to build an apk file. https://docs.flutter.dev/deployment/android#build-an-apk